# How to delete the the first row and the first column of a txt file created by merging various txt files using R?

Tags: r, csv, export, text-files

I have a folder containing several subfolders with the results of an experiment. In each folder, there is a .txt file with the name "List" that contains all the measurments in just one column.
I have been able to take together all those .txt files using the following code:

```
myFiles = list.files(path = ".", recursive = TRUE, pattern = "List.txt", full.names = TRUE)
data <- lapply(myFiles, read.table, sep="\t", header=FALSE)
names(data) <- myFiles
for(i in myFiles) 
  data[[i]]$Source = i
do.call(rbind, data)

files <- list.files(path="~/Desktop/exp/.", pattern=".txt")
DF <- NULL
for (f in files) {
  dat <- read.csv(f, header=F, sep="\t", na.strings="", colClasses="character")
  dat$file <- unlist(strsplit(f,split=".",fixed=T))[1]
  DF <- rbind(DF, dat)
}

data <- lapply(myFiles, read.table, sep="\t", header=FALSE)
combined.data <- do.call(rbind, data)

write.csv(combined.data, "~/Desktop/exp/results.csv")
```

If I do it like that, it works perfectly fine to combine all the files. However, in the .csv file that, I don't need the first column and the first row that are shown here:

[.csv file as it is exported now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJ16I.png)

The list then just continues as shown above until the last data point. Can you please give me a hint how to remove the "V1" and the numbering in the first column so that it would look like this:

[Desired format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLlDV.png)

Comment: Can you show a portion of the csv as well as the corresponding part of the current output as well as expected data frame?

Comment: Sorry, I thought, it was already clear enough with the tables I have created. There are now two pictures of how it is now and how I would like to have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is printed with row names and colnames by default. Try:

```
write.csv(combined.data, "~/Desktop/exp/results.csv",row.names=F,col.names=F)
```

Edit: `write.csv` throws an error when you give both row.names and col.names as False, so try the readr package

```
library(readr)
write_csv(combined.data, "~/Desktop/exp/results.csv",col_names=FALSE)
```

Comment: For the numbers it works great. They are not present anymore. But the "V1", written above the data points, is still there.

Comment: @Marc, try the `readr` package instead as shown